Setting bpy.context.tool_settings.gpencil_surface_offset has no effect
Why does this
bpy.context.tool_settings.gpencil_surface_offset = 0.025  # Set offset distance

have no effect on the UI side?
I do this in the context of adding a new grease pencil object like this:
import bpy

# Step 1: Add an empty Grease Pencil object
gpencil_data = bpy.data.grease_pencils.new('GreasePencilData')
gpencil_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('GreasePencil', gpencil_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(gpencil_obj)

# Step 2: Set the Grease Pencil object as active (ensure we are in Object Mode initially)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = gpencil_obj
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

# Step 3: Add a Grease Pencil layer (if none exists)
if len(gpencil_data.layers) == 0:
    gpencil_layer = gpencil_data.layers.new(name="GP_Layer", set_active=True)
else:
    gpencil_layer = gpencil_data.layers[0]

# Step 4: Add a frame to the active layer at frame 0 (if no frame exists)
if gpencil_layer.active_frame is None:
    gpencil_frame = gpencil_layer.frames.new(0)  # Add a frame at frame 0
else:
    gpencil_frame = gpencil_layer.active_frame

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='PAINT_GPENCIL')

# Access the current drawing tool settings for Grease Pencil
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

tool_settings = bpy.context.tool_settings

# Set to draw on surface
tool_settings.gpencil_stroke_placement_view3d = 'SURFACE'  # Enable drawing on surface

# Set the stroke surface offset (this will affect the distance from the surface)
print("before", tool_settings.gpencil_surface_offset)
bpy.context.tool_settings.gpencil_surface_offset = 0.025  # Set offset distance
print("after", tool_settings.gpencil_surface_offset)

bpy.ops.gpencil.stroke_smooth()  # Force an operation that uses the settings
print("after", tool_settings.gpencil_surface_offset)

# Switch back to Paint mode to retain the settings
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='PAINT_GPENCIL')
bpy.context.area.tag_redraw()  # Force redraw to ensure the settings are applied
print("again", tool_settings.gpencil_surface_offset)

print("Grease Pencil object, layer, and frame added. Drawing on surface enabled with an offset of 0.015!")


but it seems an issue no matter what I do around it.

In case anyone is using ChatGPT for help - the issue is: that's not the relevant setting.
The relevant setting is:
bpy.context.object.data.zdepth_offset = 0.001

and that works perfectly
